# How to remove class when scrollTop() = div?

Tags: jquery, css

I want to scroll to my navigation and then change the class of the navigation but my script doesn't work.

```js
$(window).scroll(function() {
  if ($(window).scrollTop == $('.menu_nav').offset().top) {
    $('.menu_nav').removeClass('menu_nav').addClass('nav_scroll');
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="menu_nav">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#">O MNĚ</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Reference</a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Kontaktuj mě</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: It would be easier for us til help you if you include the important parts of your code, Here im talking about your navigation html. If not then we can only guess what is not working.

Comment: The problem is that you are using dot's `.` in `.removeClass('.menu_nav').addClass('.nav_scroll');` it should be `.removeClass('menu_nav').addClass('nav_scroll');`

Comment: `scrollTop` is  a function and has to be called, currently you compare a function with a number. You have to write `$(window).scrollTop()`.

Comment: still not working

Answer (score 1):

The reason why your code does not work is because you are using dots (`.`) inside your `.addClass()` and `.removeClass()`

`$('.menu_nav').removeClass('.menu_nav').addClass('.nav_scroll');`
should be 
`$('.menu_nav').removeClass('menu_nav').addClass('nav_scroll');`

**Demo**

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(window).scroll(function() {
    if ($(".menu_nav").length > 0 && $(window).scrollTop() == $('.menu_nav').offset().top) {
      $('.menu_nav').removeClass('menu_nav').addClass('nav_scroll');
    }
  });
});
```

```css
.menu {
  height: 200vh;
  background: yellow;
}

.menu_nav {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: blue;
}

.nav_scroll {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="menu">
  <div class="menu_nav">
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#">O MNĚ</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">Reference</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">Kontaktuj mě</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I found out that your code works only if I scroll really slowly.